# How can I make AUCTeX use the spelling dictionary in the same language as babel is loaded with?

Tags: babel, emacs, auctex, spelling

Is it possible to setup AUCTeX so that it loads the spelling dictionary in the same language as the language used by `babel`? For example, is it possible to load the Danish ispell dictionary when a document includes `\usepackage[danish]{babel}`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This can be done by using [language specific hooks in AUCTeX](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.html#Style-Files-for-Different-Languages). To automatically load the Danish ispell dictionary when a document includes `\usepackage[danish]{babel}` put the following in your .emacs:

```lisp
(add-hook 'TeX-language-dk-hook
      (lambda () (ispell-change-dictionary "danish")))
```

Comment: Now *that* was fast! ;-)

Comment: @lockstep I have been looking for such an option and when I found it in the manual I thought it would make sense to document it here for others to find and benefit from.

Comment: What about Polyglossia?

Comment: @egreg That is a good question. I did a quick search without finding anything. Perhaps it should be asked as a new question?

Comment: @egreg I asked a new question about the polyglossia case: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39842/how-can-i-make-auctex-use-the-spelling-dictionary-in-the-same-language-as-polygl

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218512/how-can-i-change-the-language-in-emacs-when-using-ispell), you can also specify a local variable inside the `.tex` file :

```
%%% Local Variables:
%%% ispell-local-dictionary: "danish"
%%% End:
```