# How can I make AUCTeX use the spelling dictionary in the same language as polyglossia is loaded with?

Tags: emacs, auctex, polyglossia, spelling

Is it possible to setup AUCTeX so that it loads the spelling dictionary in the same language as the language used by `polyglossia`? For example, is it possible to load the Danish ispell dictionary when a document includes `\usepackage{polyglossia}` and `\setdefaultlanguage{danish}`?

The answer to [How can I make AUCTeX use the spelling dictionary in the same language as babel is loaded with?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39817/how-can-i-make-auctex-use-the-spelling-dictionary-in-the-same-language-as-babel) does not seem to apply to this case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can't test this, as I don't have multiple dictionaries on hand. But it should get you started if it doesn't work completely (to be added to your .emacs):

```lisp
;; replace the language names and dictionary paths below to suit your setup:

(defvar my-dicts 
  '(("danish" . "path-to-my-danish-dictionary") 
    ("english" . "path-to-my-english-dictionary"))
  "An alist of dictionaries to pick from")

(defun polyglossia-check ()
  "If polyglossia is loaded, sets the dictionary to the value in my-dicts
   corresponding to the value of setdefaultlanguage or setmainlanguage."
  (interactive)
  (if 
      (= (shell-command (concat "grep polyglossia " default-directory
                              TeX-auto-local "/*"))
         0)
      (save-excursion
        (beginning-of-buffer)
        (re-search-forward "\\(setdefaultlanguage\\|setmainlanguage\\){")
        (mark-word)
        (let ((lang (buffer-substring (point) (mark))))
          (setq ispell-local-dictionary (cdr (assoc lang my-dicts)))))))

(add-hook 'TeX-auto-cleanup-hook 'polyglossia-check)
```

The hook will run the whenever your document is parsed. I'm not sure how often this happens. If it doesn't seem to work, try calling `M-x polyglossia-check` explicitly.

Comment: The `\setdefaultlanguage` command can be called also `\setmainlanguage` and many people use the latter in analogy to the `\setmainfont` command of `fontspec`.

Comment: @egreg, switched to a regexp search, which should work for either form now.