# How can I make AUCTeX spell check in the language specified by babel and csquotes macros?

Tags: babel, emacs, auctex, spelling, csquotes

It is possible to [make AUCTeX load the spelling dictionary of the language which `babel` is loaded with](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39817/how-can-i-make-auctex-use-the-spelling-dictionary-in-the-same-language-as-babel). One further convenience would be for it to appropriately react to changes of language within a document. Such changes can be made with macros of `babel` and `csquotes`. So, is it possible to make AUCTeX spell check in the correct language according to the language macros of a document?

Here follows a test document. A solution would make AUCTeX automatically spell check the first paragraph in English and the other paragraphs should be spell checked according to the specified language.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[danish,english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\begin{document}

In computing, a spell checker (or spell check) is an application
program that flags words in a document that may not be spelled
correctly.

\foreignquote{danish}{I computerterminologi er en stavekontrol en
design feature eller et software program designet til at tjekke
stavningen af ord i et dokument og som normalt kan komme med forslag
til stavningsforslag.}

\hyphenquote{danish}{I computerterminologi er en stavekontrol en
design feature eller et software program designet til at tjekke
stavningen af ord i et dokument og som normalt kan komme med forslag
til stavningsforslag.}

\foreignlanguage{danish}{I computerterminologi er en stavekontrol en
design feature eller et software program designet til at tjekke
stavningen af ord i et dokument og som normalt kan komme med forslag
til stavningsforslag.}

\begin{hyphenrules}{danish} I computerterminologi er en stavekontrol
en design feature eller et software program designet til at tjekke
stavningen af ord i et dokument og som normalt kan komme med forslag
til stavningsforslag.
\end{hyphenrules}

This sentence should be spell checked with an English dictionary.

\end{document}
```

Comment: I do not use Emacs nor I type these days in any other language than English but I think this a very interesting question. Personally, I use ispell and a custom key binding to call it from nvi to do spell checking interactively (I like to confirm changes). Basically what you are asking is much more sophisticated script which will terminate ispell when Danish is encountered change default dictionary to Danish and continue spelling. I will ask my CS students to try to come up with something.

Comment: @PredragPunosevac I would also like for it to work with fly spell because that what I currently use for spell checking. Would appreciate any lead on this issue. Make answering my question your students' home work!

Comment: I am not sure about the homework but a small project yes. Emacs is written in Lisp so they will have to hack Lisp code not shell script as I described for nvi but I think it should be duable.

Comment: I think this is rather difficult. I could imagine to advise `ispell-region` accordingly, but, probably, the only way to go is to use a spell checker backend providing this – certainly useful – feature.

Comment: @mhp Why so pessimistic? Given Emacs extensibility I think it is very possible. It is just a matter of coming up with an appropriate logic and implementing it. One way would be for flyspell to start spell checking in some default language then change dictionary every time there is some babel expression changing language. This seems doable as long as you can come up with the right lisp code to recognize the babel expressions, i.e. some regular expressions.

Comment: I don’t say it’s impossible – I’m not familiar with the code of the `ispell` and `flyspell` libraries, although I know some deficiencies. Nonetheless, I think that it’s much more worth adding such a feature to the TeX mode of a capable spell checker backend (such as `hunspell`).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Assuming you are using `flyspell`, yes it is possible!

The package [flyspell-babel.el](https://github.com/phimuemue/emacs-hacks/blob/master/flyspell-babel.el) should do exactly what you want: read inline language changes for babel, and start a `flyspell` process for that language.

According to the documentation:

> The parsing done by this package has its limits limited, and so it
>   will not work with arbitrary LaTeX code.  I hope that these
>   restrictions will not in practice impinge on the typical usage of
>   most people.  The first language declaration is usually determined
>   by the final language option passed to the babel `\usepackage`
>   command, which takes effect after \begin{document}.  Thereafter,
>   you can switch the declared language with `\selectlanguage`
>   statements, `otherlanguage` environments, and `\foreignlanguage`
>   commands.  You can also define your own language-switching
>   commands, and register these with flyspell-babel.

Therefore, you may have to make your other language change commands, such as `\foreignquote`, known to `flyspell-babel`.

This package requires the package `flyspell-multi.el` (no known link at the moment) or [`ispell-multi.el`](https://github.com/phimuemue/emacs-hacks/blob/master/ispell-multi.el) to start several `flyspell` processes at the same time, to avoid slowdowns when scrolling through a file with language changes.

### Installation instructions

Put the files `flyspell-babel.el` and `flyspell-multi.el` somewhere in [the load-path](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/emacs-faq.html#Changing-load_002dpath) and add the following lines to your `.emacs`:

```lisp
(autoload 'flyspell-babel-setup "flyspell-babel")
(add-hook 'latex-mode-hook 'flyspell-babel-setup)
```

To add support for other commands, add the following lines to your `.emacs`:

```lisp
(add-to-list 'flyspell-babel-command-alist ("hyphenquote" "hyphenquote"))
(add-to-list 'flyspell-babel-command-alist ("foreignquote" "foreignquote"))
(add-to-list 'flyspell-babel-environment-alist ("hyphenrules" "hyphenrules"))
```

All credit goes to [Peter Heslin](https://community.dur.ac.uk/p.j.heslin/Software/Emacs/), the author of these two packages.

Comment: Your answer would be even better if you also provided descriptions on how install and use the packages.

Comment: @N.N. Instructions can usually be found in the comments of the .el file, but you are right, I might as well post them in the above.

Comment: I tried your installation instructions and it works for `\foreignlanguage` in my example but neither of the other macros. Perhaps you could include instructions on how to cover them as well.

Comment: @N.N. I editted my answer with what I think will work, but I'm not pro at elisp, and I don't have flyspell on this computer to try out myself... I think the syntax should be more or less correct, but it may miss a few quotes or parentheses.

Comment: Two years later I couldn't download the *.el files form the places above, but they can be found here: https://github.com/phimuemue/emacs-hacks. The package is great!

Comment: @OlegDomanov Thank you for the information, I will update the post.

Comment: Do [`ispell-multi.el`](https://community.dur.ac.uk/p.j.heslin/Software/Emacs/) and [`flyspell-babel.el`](https://community.dur.ac.uk/p.j.heslin/Software/Emacs/) work with recent Emacs (e.g., GNU Emacs version 24.5.1)? I keep getting: "**Flyspell-babel warning: no dictionary installed for foreignlanguage**," and it doesn't change the dictionary when I change the language environment I'm in. See my question: "[Flyspell-babel warning: no dictionary installed for foreignlanguage](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/325453/36603)."