# Flyspell-babel warning: no dictionary installed for foreignlanguage

Tags: babel, emacs, spelling, flyspell

I am trying to get Peter Heslin's [`ispell-multi.el`](https://community.dur.ac.uk/p.j.heslin/Software/Emacs/) and [`flyspell-babel.el`](https://community.dur.ac.uk/p.j.heslin/Software/Emacs/)  working with the custom commands:

```
\newcommand{\fli}[1]{\foreignlanguage{latin}{\textit{#1}}}
\newcommand{\fl}[1]{\foreignlanguage{latin}{#1}}
\newcommand{\fii}[1]{\foreignlanguage{italian}{\textit{#1}}}
\newcommand{\fgi}[1]{\foreignlanguage{german}{\textit{#1}}}
```

and languages

```
\usepackage[italian,german,latin,french]{babel}
```

When I enter `flyspell-babel-mode`, it successfully loads French sometimes, but it mostly throws this warning:

```
Flyspell-babel warning: no dictionary installed for foreignlanguage
```

and does not switch the dictionary depending what language environment I'm in; yet I am able to load all the languages' dictionaries manually with `ispell-change-dictionary`. They are named the same as Babel's names for them.

[Flyspell-babel](https://community.dur.ac.uk/p.j.heslin/Software/Emacs/) does work if I explicitly write, e.g.,

```
\foreignlanguage{latin}{<Latin text here>}
```

Here's what's in my `~/.emacs`:

```
(load-file "ispell-multi.el")
(load-file "flyspell-babel.el")
(autoload 'flyspell-babel-setup "flyspell-babel")
(add-hook 'latex-mode-hook 'flyspell-babel-setup)

(setq flyspell-babel-verbose t)

(setq flyspell-babel-to-ispell-alist
       '(("german" "german")
         ("italian" "italian")
         ("latin" "latin")))

(setq flyspell-babel-command-alist
      '(("fgi" "german")
        ("fii" "italian")
        ("fl" "latin")
    ("fli" "latin")))
```

I am using GNU Emacs 24.5.1.

<sup>For more information on [`flyspell-babel`](https://community.dur.ac.uk/p.j.heslin/Software/Emacs/), see the question: "[How can I make AUCTeX spell check in the language specified by babel and csquotes macros?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40988/36603)" and [its chosen answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/82191/36603).</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(setq flyspell-babel-verbose t)

(setq flyspell-babel-to-ispell-alist
       '(("german" "german")
         ("italian" "italian")
         ("latin" "latin")))

(setq flyspell-babel-command-alist
      '(("fgi" "german")
        ("fii" "italian")
        ("fl" "latin")
    ("fli" "latin")))
```

should be in `flyspell-babel.el`, not in `~/.emacs`.