# How to spellcheck multi-language LaTeX files?

Tags: babel, emacs, spelling, flyspell

Continuing http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/325453/flyspell-babel-warning-no-dictionary-installed-for-foreignlanguage and [How can I make AUCTeX spell check in the language specified by babel and csquotes macros?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40988/how-can-i-make-auctex-spell-check-in-the-language-specified-by-babel-and-csquote/82191#82191),
let's take as an example the following file in UTF-8:

```
Außenwirkung
Nutzungsfälle
\foreignlanguage{USenglish}{behavior}
\foreignlanguage{UKenglish}{behaviour}
%%% Local Variables:
%%% mode: latex
%%% ispell-local-dictionary: "german-new8"
%%% coding: utf-8
%%% End:
```

It is `\input` from another main file, which contains `\usepackage[USenglish,british,french,norsk,dutch,latin,german,ngerman]{babel}`
I typically use emacs 26.1 for editing with aspell 0.60.7-20110707 for spellchecking (but I'm ready to change my habits if there's a better solution for spellchecking). The German words are checked without problems (of course, you might wish to add them to your local dictionary if they are not in the global one).  The English words are problematic: each time I run `M-x ispell-buffer`, they show up as wrong. Is there any way to automatically check also the `\foreignlanguage{...}{...}` parts using the proper dictionary? As of now, flyspell-babel is unfortunately dead or at least seems dead to me (cf. http://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/25319/wie-bringe-ich-flyspell-babel-zum-laufen).

Crossposts: http://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=54&t=32702, http://golatex.de/viewtopic,p,107348.html

Comment: Spell checking is an editor function, not LaTeX per se.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Sure. But questions were asked and answered here on this topic as of 2016. Has the scope of tex.se been narrowed since then in this regard?

Comment: I think you'll have more chances of an answer posting this at the emacs stackexchange: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/.  As already mentioned, this is not a LaTeX feature, so few people here will know how to answer this (not impossible, of course, but harder).

Comment: Is each file of your project in one language? I am using `hunspell`, which I call from R with `pythontex`. It is not the simplest of solutions, but works (mostly). My spellchecking options were limited because of language I am working with; OS windows and my employer IT rules. For english, there are also other options - through lua or perl; but none of them I have tested.